# Define variable using read from stdin of heredoc

Tags: bash, variable, echo, here-document, shellcheck

I am trying to store Available and Total Memory into variables in a script file as follows,

```
read -r Available Total <<EOT
$(free -m | awk '/^Mem/{print $7; print $2;}')
EOT

$ echo $Total

$ echo $Available
1437
```

But I am unable to store the variable $Total.

But when I do:

```
$ read Available Total <<EOT
$(echo $(free -m | awk '/^Mem/{print $7; print $2;}'))
EOT

$ echo $Available
1309
$ echo $Total
7865
```

It works. But shellcheck gives me following suggestion:

`Useless echo? Instead of 'echo $(cmd)', just use 'cmd'. [SC2005]`

Why the forst example didn't work? and Why the second one works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `awk` command prints the two values on two separate lines, while `read` reads one line, expecting to find two fields on it.

Change the `print` command to `print $7, $2;` to print the numbers on the same line. Since you tagged this with Bash, you can use a here-string instead of a here-doc to make the full command a bit neater:

```
$ read -r Available Total <<< $( free -m | awk '/^Mem/{print $7, $2;}' )
```

Or use a process substitution:

```
$ read -r Available Total <   <( free -m | awk '/^Mem/{print $7, $2;}' )
```

---

If you use `echo $(...)` without quotes around the command substitution, the output from the command gets word-split, and `echo` sees the separate lines as separate arguments. It prints all of its arguments joined with spaces, so on a single line.

`echo $(foo)` is usually rather a useless thing to do, but isn't the same same just `foo`, for this very reason. It also puts a final newline at the end of the output of `foo`, if it wasn't there already.

Comment: [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) would work here as well.

Comment: @glennjackman This doesn't work `read -r Available Total <(free -m | awk '/^Mem/{print $7, $2;}')` Could you please correct this?

Comment: @Nikhil, process substitution needs the redirection operator `<` here. In itself it just expands to a (pseudo)filename, which `read` would take as the name of a variable to write to. (It's probably something like `/dev/fd/63`, which isn't a valid variable name so you get an error.)

Comment: Yes, `read` reads stdin, so you need a redirection.